Where is the documentation that describes how to code a select element for ASP NET Core MVC?
I spent several hours getting a <select> element to work correctly, and in the end, the solution came from trying random stuff, rather than from anything I could find on the internet.
I was able to populate the dropdown easily, but getting the selected value back in the POST proved a lot more difficult.
Where am I?
I know I'm using an ASP.NET Core 8 MVC app created using ASPNET Zero, but the finer detail is hazy. I've been getting search results like this one, but I assume there's something different about the context (even though I am also using ASP.NET Core tag helpers), because the examples don't work for me.
Not knowing what my context is called makes it difficult to focus my Googling.
My code
Here's my view model:
public class CreateOrEditVisitorLogModalViewModel
{
    public CreateOrEditVisitorLogDto VisitorLog { get; set; }
    public List<StaffMemberDto> StaffMembers { get; set; }
}

Here's CreateOrEditVisitorLogDto:
public class CreateOrEditVisitorLogDto : EntityDto<long?>
{
    public DateTime ArrivalTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DepartureTime { get; set; }
    public string VisitorName { get; set; }
    public string Visiting { get; set; }
}

Here's my dropdown; this is the part that took me ages to get right:
<select
    name="visiting"
    asp-for="@Model.VisitorLog.Visiting"
    asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.StaffMembers, nameof(StaffMemberDto.Id), nameof(StaffMemberDto.Name)))"
    class="form-control">

    <option value="">--- select one ---</option>

</select>


If I remove the asp-for attribute, it makes no difference - the form posts back the value selected in the dropdown to the server.
If I change the value of the name attribute or remove it (i.e., make it look like this example), the selected value doesn't get posted back to the server.

The question
Where is the documentation that says what you need to do to get a select list to populate the "target" (I mean, the string item it's supposed to populate when posting back) in my context, and which described exactly what to put in the name attribute?

Probably the easiest thing to do would be to insert one of the following below your <select> then review the HTML in the browser. It should give you an idea what is missing in yours. Add a @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Visiting, Model.StaffMembers, new {@class="form-control"})  ListboxFor or DropDownFor are Razor's default wrappers to generate <select> elements.

In most cases the formdata being post back to the server will not be complete entities, and they will never be tracked "real" entities, just DTOs cast as entities. If you get a StaffMemberId for the selected Visitng, you should fetch that StaffMember from the DbContext to associate to the entity you are inserting or updating, Even if Visiting was fully populated, it will be a new instance when the server method receives it and treated as an insert, not an association to an existing row.

For me it looks like lacking basic HTML + JS knowledge - that's the base for client-side development

@MichałTurczyn, Could you elaborate?  I was assuming it hinges on the behaviour of the tag helpers, and some "magic" which relates form elements to the DTO returned to the controller.  Am I writing the HTML incorrectly?  Should I be writing some JS to populate my model?  Or is there some JS I'm not looking at?  Where?

Explanation

You need firstly know that asp-for tag helper will generate the id and name element in frontend(refer to here).
But if you specify the name attribute in the html, the tag helper default generated name value will be override.

Model binding looks through the sources for the name pattern prefix.property_name. If nothing is found, it looks for just property_name without the prefix.


Conclusion

If your backend need receive parameter like:
public IActionResult Post(CreateOrEditVisitorLogDto model)




One way is add the name attribute like what you did(name="Visiting").

The other way, if you keep using asp-for="@Model.VisitorLog.Visiting" without adding the name attribute, you can use [Bind(Prefix ="VisitorLog")] to specify the prefix:
public IActionResult Post([Bind(Prefix ="VisitorLog")]CreateOrEditVisitorLogDto model)




If your backend need receive parameter like:
public IActionResult Post(CreateOrEditVisitorLogModalViewModel model)

Just using asp-for="@Model.VisitorLog.Visiting" should work fine.



I can't decorate with the attribute you're suggesting because I don't actually have access to the part where the back end receives the form - I think it's automatically generated by ASPNET Zero (something I've never used before).  The first my code sees of the posted form is in the app service.  Maybe that's why this isn't working per the other examples I've found.

Hi @OutstandingBill, ASPNET Zero? It seems to be a third party framework. What I shared works fine in ASP.NET Core.
